What does Readonly<T> & T mean in TypeScript?
Here is a snippet from Vue 3 source code.
export type StrictUnwrapSlotsType<
  S extends SlotsType,
  T = NonNullable<S[typeof SlotSymbol]>,
> = [keyof S] extends [never] ? Slots : Readonly<T> & T

interface User {
  name: string,
  age: number
}

type intersectionUser = Readonly<User> & User
// result in:
// type intersectionUser = {
//    name: string;
//    age: number;
//}

This looks like Readonly<T> & T  and T are the same.
Why does this return Readonly<T> & T instead of directly returning T?

To indicate, that T is Readonly?

@Justinas but 1. Readonly<T> would indicate that 2. The result is not readonly Readonly<T> & T should be essentially the same as T and any properties not reaadonly in T will remain not readonly since the intersection of {readonly foo: string} & {foo: string} results in {foo: string} https://tsplay.dev/m3dMbW

Here is the pull request that added & T: https://github.com/vuejs/core/pull/8374 It contains an explanation why it was added.

I don't see why this question was closed as opinion-based. There is a factual answer like @JSONDerulo found. Voted to reopen.

It was added with the following pull request: https://github.com/vuejs/core/pull/8374
The reason is that with Readonly, it is not possible to call functions, which caused issues in that particular case.
